# How do I set a unix process to autorun in a particular run level?

Tags: unix, autorun, runlevel, init.rc

I have a stand alone server application that I would like to run automatically when my red hat box starts up.  My default run level is 5 but I want to make sure it works both in run level 3 & 5.

Answers appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's /etc/rc.d/rcX.d directory for each runlevel X. Symlink apropriate [S]tart and/or [K]ill scripts to /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/ and /etc/rc.d/rc5.d

The scripts are run as sorted by number. This way you can organize dependencies.

The scripts per se are in /etc/init.d/

Comment: Also - on BSD (inherited by Slackware), runlevels are actually found in `/etc/rc.d/rc.*` - that is strictly a Debian/RH view of things.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [chkconfig](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4445)

Example:

```
chkconfig [servicename] on
```

This normally actives the service on runlevel 3 and 5.

Comment: +1, I liked this when still using Red Hat / Fedora. It's not available on other distros than RH-based ones, is it?

Comment: It is available on Ubuntu and on Cent-OS. I use it regularly.

Comment: Ah, so it seems; http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/chkconfig. Cool!