# Change CPUfreq in runlevel 1?

Tags: ubuntu, overclocking, runlevel

I would like to change my cpu speed using runlevel 1 on Ubuntu 8.10: the problem is when I try to run cpufreq_selector -f 2330000 (for instance), the following message appears:

`Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory.`

Then I figured out why, its because `system_bus_socket` runs as a daemon. and in Runlevel 1 mod all daemons are killed.

So my question is: is there a way to not kill this daemon? (so that i'll be able to select my CPU freq in runlevel 1)

Thank you for any answer!

NB: for those who're wondering why I must use Runlevel 1, the answer is that I need my OS to have less running tasks as possible, in order to performe some performance benching on my system.

Comment: Could you change the title of the post to "Start a service by default in a runlevel" or something similar, since that's what you're effectively asking?

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly set the daemon to run during runlevel 1.  You can also start a daemon by running its `/etc/init.d/foo start` if you just need it once and not started every time.

Assuming `dbus` is the name of the service you're wanting to run, use one of these commands to start it during runlevel 1.

Ubuntu's "native" tool for this is `update-rc.d` ([manpage](http://www.annodex.net/cgi-bin/man/man2html?update-rc.d+8)).  Check when the service is currently run and killed; on my Debian system, `dbus` is started at 12 and killed at 88.  You'll want to substitute numbers from your own system:

```
sudo update-rc.d dbus start 12 1 2 3 4 5 . stop 88 0 6
                   ^        ^   ^^^^^^^         ^   ^^
                   |        |      |            |    |
                   |        |      |            |    --- kill at these runlevels
                   |        |      |            -------- ordering for stopping service
                   |        |      --- start at these runlevels    
                   |        ---------- ordering for start
                   --- service name
```

You could also use `chkconfig` ([manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig)), available in [Ubuntu's universe repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/chkconfig).  It's a little simpler for just enabling a service on a new runlevel:

```
sudo chkconfig --level 1 dbus on
```

Here's a good reference for [managing services and runlevels on Ubuntu](http://pthree.org/2008/02/27/managing-services-in-ubuntu-part-ii-managing-runlevels/).  Also see this related question: [How do I set a Unix process to autorun in a particular run level?](https://superuser.com/questions/15869/how-do-i-set-a-unix-process-to-autorun-in-a-particular-run-level).

Comment: +1 Excellent answer.  I wish I could up vote it twice just for the ascii art

Comment: @DaveParillo: thx, but the format's shamelessly stolen from other posts on this site.  too many arguments to that command not to explain it somehow.  :)

Comment: chkconfig shouldn't be used on Debian/Ubuntu; it won't work when some leftover startup scripts aren't purged. Use sysv-rc-conf instead. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromLinux#Services,%20Chkconfig%20and%20Initscripts and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chkconfig/+bug/450517