# How can I run script when I start up my Linux machine?

Tags: linux, boot, python

I would like to run the python script, when I startup the Linux machine. How can I do so? I don't need the user to login the OS to start the script. (The user is password protected.)

Comment: What distribution? Are you using `upstart`, `systemd`, or something else?

Comment: Have you done much research into this? The top results when Googling your question comes up with links that say the exact same thing as the below answer from mnmnc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a script run upon startup of the Ubuntu machine?](http://superuser.com/questions/155476/how-do-i-make-a-script-run-upon-startup-of-the-ubuntu-machine)

Comment: @Indrek: It's not an exact duplicate, since this post does not specify Ubuntu, while the question is somewhat distro-specific.

Answer (score 5):

Generic method – add the script to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
/usr/bin/python pythonscript.py
```

if your python interpreter is under `/usr/bin`, or simply

```
/path/to/pythonscript.py
```

if your script is marked executable (+x).

Note that some systems use `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` instead.

---

On *systemd* systems, rc.local might be ignored completely.

Create a service unit, `/etc/systemd/system/something.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Script name

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/script.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Tell *systemd* to start the script on boot with `systemctl enable something.service`.

Comment: Although Ted explicitly asks about OS startup and not about user login, the proper place for post-login scripts is `.profile`, `.xprofile` and/or `.config/autostart/`. Adding something to `.bashrc` will cause it to be run *every time a terminal is opened*.

Comment: Just to note: on some systems, the file may be located at `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`.

Comment: @clpo13: And some systems might not be using `rc.local` at all (such as most *systemd*-using Linux distros)...