# Change ubuntu defaul runlevel

Tags: ubuntu, init, runlevel

i need change default runlevel to ubuntu server 14.04. I installed GUI to manage the hp printers and now i need return to runlevel 3, i edit the file `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` and modify the line:

```
env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=2
```

to

```
env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=3
```

But every boot start in graphical mode

Comment: Did it worked `sudo init 3` ? The default place in RH were ` /etc/inittab` if I remember well. I see you have done as suggested [here](http://serverfault.com/a/147440).

Comment: yes, but it happens nothing

Comment: You may find interesting to read this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/615639/196535) for grub setting of the RUNLEVEL. Why did you change the default level and not only the current one? BTW the differences between RUNLEVEL 2 and 3 is the [network support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel).

Comment: OK, how stop the graphical mode on boot?

Comment: Please make it more clean, do you mean the [X display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29)? In case which is (lightdm...)? Search directly for the one you need. PS>I don't know if your Ubuntu has a _SystemV_ or _upstart_ as [it seems](http://superuser.com/questions/151330/ubuntu-control-the-init-startup?rq=1). They have different RUNLEVEL 3 meanings. If your question is different from the one you posted, please [edit] it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved adding `text` to line in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

type after:

```
update-grub
```

and reboot, now works!

Comment: So you forced it from grub. Good. Glad that the [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/615634/how-to-set-default-runlevel/615639#615639) about the  grub setting of the RUNLEVEL pointed you on the right direction. Please [edit] your answer and add some reference that you found of the value admitted for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` it can help someone else too. :)